# High-side current sensing using PNP

Tags: bjt, current-sensing, high-side

I have the following three states:
State 1: When system is active with transducers, current through the load is approximately 350 mA.
State 2: When system is activated without transducers, current through the load is approximately 100 mA.
State 3: When in stand-by mode, current through the load is approximately 70 mA.

I am trying to sense current through the load to differentiate between states using a high-side current sense resistor. Supply voltage: 24 VDC.

I have the schematics as below, which would work if I increased the sense resistor to 3 Ω. This is not ideal, as I would like to keep the voltage drop across R1 under 2 V.

I understand I can use a high-side differential amplifier or current sense amplifier and easily solve this problem, but I would like to learn if there is a way to simplify the solution without an op-amp, since there is no precision required here.

Mainly, I need to verify either in State 1 or in State 2/3. Is there a way to differentiate between all 3 states without an op-amp?

[image]

Comment: How do you want to differentiate  states? Three solo on/off “digital” outputs? Or one analog output like 0V for state1, 1V for state2, …?

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't have a current source but instead a 24 V source. If so, how much of that 24 V can your load afford to lose in making a measurement? Also, is this a one-off circuit?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It will be digital input to a microcontroller if detection is only between State 1 and State 2/3. To detect all 3, it would be analog input to ADC..

Comment: I can afford to have 3V drop across the resistor. Technically, it's not a problem in this application. But I would like to learn my options if in future when I can not afford to have more Vdrop. How can I sense using a BJT / amplify voltage to get it at more than Vbe using small sense resistor...

Comment: @user101095 Have you considered a current mirror with the diode-connected side supplying the load? The voltage drop can be quite low, even with 100 mV degeneration and beta-compensation added to it.

Comment: Use a germanium PNP like AC122 or 2N217, they will work with 1 ohm as R1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how the +24V supply or the transducers are connected, so I'm left to guess.

I don't see a way to sense 70mA without amplification, if you insist on a sense resistance under \$\frac{0.7V}{70mA} = 10\Omega\$. The only idea I have is to amplify the sense resistor's voltage, which can be done with two transistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgSpKE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is how \$V_{OUT}\$ varies with load current \$I_1\$:

[image]

This has a gain of \$\frac{R_5}{R_4}=10\$, meaning that over a range of 1A, the voltage across sense resistor R1 changes from 0V to 0.47V, and consequently \$V_{OUT}\$ changes by about tens times that.

Even at 1A the sense resistor drops less than half a volt.

There's an offset to \$V_{OUT}\$ which needs to be accounted for, but at least you have clear threshold potentials corresponding to 70mA, 100mA and 350mA.

---

This looks like a a current mirror, but it's not being operated in the same way. As with a mirror, Q1 and Q2 emitters have the same potential, and Q1's role is to bias Q2 to achieve that. Unlike a current mirror the potentials at the top of R2 and R4 are *not* equal, due to the potential difference across sense resistor R1.

This potential difference is what causes Q2 emitter current to vary while Q1 emitter current stays fixed. Q2's collector current varies similarly, resulting in the voltage across R5 varying ten times more than the voltage across R4, and that's where we get a voltage gain of 10. The right-side is really just a common-base class A amplifier.

Unfortunately the current in each path (Q1 and Q2) is non-zero, and even without any load there is current through R1, and a potential difference across it, giving rise to a greater-than-expected permanent offset at the output.

This offset will also vary with supply voltage (+24V here), since quiescent current is highly dependent upon that, so common-mode voltage gain is quite significant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to simulate this with R2 and R4 changed to 1K and got the following results. Pardon my understanding on Current mirror but have questions on the results as follows: With I1: 0.350A, IR4: 85uA, Vout: 8.5V. With I1: 0.1A, IR4: 186uA, Vout: 18.6V. With I1: 0.07A, IR4: 200uA, Vout: 19.9V. IR2 remains same in all cases at 230uA. I should be able to use voltage divider to convert Vout to 0- 3.3V scale for uC. But why is the current through R2 and R4 different? Shouldn't current mirror keep the same current flowing through both transistors?

Comment: @user101095 I've appended some notes to my answer, to address your questions.

Comment: The notes in the answers were helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here the 350mA load current on 4.7ohm shunt makes 1.645V shunt drop.

1.645V across 330ohm forces 5mA current through 1k ,so it outputs 5V.

[image]

Note: The diode compensates the transistor Vbe drop.

If you change 1k to 2k2 the output voltages will be 2.2 times higher (11V, 3.12V, 2.18V) so it will be easier to compare it or work with.

Comment: thank you but, With 4.7 ohm sense at max current of 0.7Amps, I will have 3.3V drop. If this is acceptable, I can just increase R1 to 3 ohm in my circuit and I will have enough Vbe to turn on Q1 at 0.35Amp and will have max 2.1V drop at full load..

Comment: I didn’t know about 700mA. However, my schematic allows using shunt whatever you want (like 2.2ohm,..). Change the 330 ohm according gain needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with only one transistor, your only threshold / reference voltage is its Vbe, so you can detect or trigger on only one current level.  For a small-signal part such as a 2N3906, conduction starts at around Vbe = 0.5 V.

The load current mid-point between 100 mA and 350 mA is 225 mA.  Using Ohm's Law, the sense resistor should be approx. 2.2 ohms.  Without a different shunt arrangement or more complex circuitry, I think that's all you get.

Answer (score 0):

The wildar or wilson current mirrors though more complex are probably a better fit. I have used both. Here is a good presentation. https://slideplayer.com/slide/2315840/